# Is there a way to dynamically generate Spring Data Jpa queries?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing an app using Spring Boot, Spring Data. And I'm trying to implement a filtering feature based on different filter parameters.

Using Spring Data queries we can define quite complex logic, e.g.:

```java
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = 1")
Collection<User> findAllActiveUsers();
```

But what if the number of where clauses, order, limit, number of different parameters are unknown till we make an actual filter request which can be quite complex.

Right now filter params are send in a json object which I parse and retrieve them and the result sql query can be something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE field1 != `value1` and (field1 != ` value2 `OR (field1 = `value3` AND filed2 < 3))
AND field2 != 99
```

Is it possible to generate dynamically complex queries with undefined (till the actual filter request, during runtime) number of params, where clauses and other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this active project  RSQL for JPA

https://github.com/perplexhub/rsql-jpa-specification

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back I wrote an article on [Spring Data JPA Query with Dynamic Where Clause](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2017/01/spring-data-jpa-with-dynamic-where.html). In this example you can send a Where Clause and Map of parameters for that. You can make use of this and modify it a bit suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Spring JPA Specification 
ref : https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: I've also found such thing as Spring Data Rest which out of the box supports filtering and all other stuff which seems to be relevant to my case. Do you know if it worth exploring it? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Spring Data Rest does CRUD services and filtering, sorting etc.
Yes its worth exploring @Coffemanz 
By using Specification you will get more control over how queries are formed, like joins, entity graphs etc
If that doesn't matter or simple table structure ,you can use Spring Data Rest

Answer (score 0):

To build it in a type safe manner, you can use [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Dynamic-Queries).